# Java Runtime check if library exits

Tags: android, android-runtime

Is this any simple way to check if a library (using nickname) is loadable in JAVA? I'm working on Android and trying to load `libavutil`, which is a `c` library, I need to check if this library is available to the system to load.

Comment: Why?  WHy not just add the library to your app so you know its available?  Expecting it to be available is asking for trouble, not only will its availability vary between OEMs and models, but they'll also be unknown versions.

Comment: I have added the library. However, due to not exactly known reasons (probably library not compatible with the destination cpu architecture), sometimes its not loaded. Hence I'm trying to find if  it is loadable.